# Looping through fields in TextFieldParser in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using TextFielParse to parse through a CSV file with 10 columns and 100 rows. 
I am interested in first and 3rd column of each row. 
How do I skip once the 3rd column is processed and move to the next row to process?
Currently it is going through all the 10 columns

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"c:\20140513_134709.csv"))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");

                parser.ReadLine();

                int regSeqNo = 0;
                bool isNumerical = false;
                string mailDate = string.Empty;
                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    //Processing row
                    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

                    foreach (string field in fields)
                    {


                         isNumerical = int.TryParse(fields[0].ToString(), out regSeqNo);
                         mailDate = fields[2].ToString();
                        continue;

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are micro-optimizing for no good reason.  The cost of reading the line is **many** times the cost of splitting it into fields.  And you never want to skip a basic check on `fields.Length`.  The foreach loop is pointless however and what got you into trouble, just index the array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code to get the required

```
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                //Processing row
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();


               isNumerical = int.TryParse(fields[0].ToString(), out regSeqNo);
               mailDate = fields[2].ToString();

            }

Inner loop is not required :)
```